# How Do I delete these orphan records from my Table, Iteratively?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables like this

1. words(word_id, value);
2. word_map(sno(auto_inc), wm_id, service_id, word_id, base_id, root_id);

   - in which sno is auto incremented just for indexing.
   - wm_id is the actual id which are unique for each service like
     (serviceid, wm_id together form a unique key).
   - base_id and root_id are referenced to wm_id i.e., I store the values of respective wm_id of new word being inserted.

My Requirement now is I want to delete the records from this table where, a words's base_id or root_id does not exists in the table

For example,

A new word with tr_id = 4, its base_id = 2 and root_id = 1 then There must two other records with tr_id s 2 and 1 if not we can call it as an orphan and that record with wm_id = 4 must be deleted, then records with other wm_ids having this 4 as base_id or root_id must also be deleted as they r also now orphans if 4 gets deleted and so on.

Can anybody suggest me the solution for the problem.

### What I tried:

I tried write a procedure using while in which it has a query like,

delete from words_map where base_id not in (select wm_id from words_map) or root_id not in (select wm_id from words_map)
But deleting/ or updating on same table using this kind of nested queries is not possible, So I am searching for an alternate way.

### What I doubt is :

- I thought of reading these wm_ids into an array  then reading one by one deleting based on that, but I dont think we have arrays in stored
  procedures.
- Is Cursor an alternative for this sitution.
- or any other best solution for this problem.

EDIT 1: Please go through this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4b6f/15 for clear experimental data

Any and early help would be appreciated

Comment: show sample data and desire output

Comment: Why is this tagged with mysql **and** Oracle? Which one are you using?

Comment: irrespective of the dbms s problem is same right, Any dependencies??

Comment: Please check my updated Question in which I added sqlfiddle with some experimental data or click here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4b6f/15